# what is the best way to remove rusty screws from old deck boards?

Tags: reclaimed-wood

I took down an old mahogany deck and saved the wood for other projects.  I have made a bike rack out of the reclaimed wood and am considering making a picnic table but I am finding it difficult to remove the old rusty screws.  Many are stripped and tend to break.  i do not want to ruin my equipment by hitting a screw when cutting/finishing.

Comment: Hi Elwood!  This question is, as Matt said, pretty much a duplicate of the mentioned question.  We're going to close this question in an effort to keep all of the answers and discussion in one place, which would be question mentioned.  Thanks for participating in the site!  Please feel free to ask more questions.